# Is there a difference between `(bool?)value == true` and `value == null ? false : (bool) value`, where value is of type object?

Tags: c#, .net

Given `value` is of type `object`, and will only ever have values of `null`, `true` or `false`, is there any difference between (a) behaviour and (b) execution of the following two expressions:

```cs
// Expression 1
value == null ? false : (bool) value
```

```cs
// Expression 2
(bool?) value == true
```

Comment: Expected to have values `null`, `true` or `false`, or will definitely never contain anything except these three options? Also, have you considered `value is true`?

Comment: @GSerg Let's say it will definitely never contain anything other than those three options, so as to remove consideration of differences in exception messages if other values are present.

Comment: So `value` is a boxed `bool?` ?

Comment: @GuruStron Or a `null` `object` without a boxed `bool?` inside.

Comment: @GSerg AFAIK runtime does not actually boxes `bool? x = null`.

Comment: If `value` always is a `bool?` the two expressions are equivalent. If is some other type both might throw an exception if the cast is invalid

Comment: @GuruStron It does not, but the `value` variable is typed `object` here.

Comment: Declaring the parameter or variable as dynamic? simplifies the expression to value == true

Comment: It would appear from the IL that expression2 is way more expensive than expression1. And that the `is true` version is slightly more expensive than expression1.

Comment: I don't think you could say "`value` is always a `bool?`" as it is actually an `object` with values of `null` or (boxed) `true` or `false`.  I don't think you can ever have a variable of type `object` on which you could call `.GetType()` and see `System.Nullable<bool>`. I think that on conversion to `object` the underlying value is boxed, or else `null`.

Comment: @GSerg Interesting! Could you write it up as an answer, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the `object value` can only contain `null`, `true` or `false`, they both will return the same result. However the second one is (unsurprisingly) more expensive:

Expression 1:

```
IL_0008: ldloc.0
IL_0009: brfalse.s IL_0013

IL_000b: ldloc.0
IL_000c: unbox.any [System.Runtime]System.Boolean
IL_0011: br.s IL_0014
```

Expression 2:

```
IL_0008: ldloc.0
IL_0009: unbox.any valuetype [System.Runtime]System.Nullable`1<bool>
IL_000e: stloc.2
IL_000f: ldc.i4.1
IL_0010: stloc.3
IL_0011: ldloca.s 2
IL_0013: call instance !0 valuetype [System.Runtime]System.Nullable`1<bool>::GetValueOrDefault()
IL_0018: ldloc.3
IL_0019: ceq
IL_001b: ldloca.s 2
IL_001d: call instance bool valuetype [System.Runtime]System.Nullable`1<bool>::get_HasValue()
IL_0022: and
IL_0023: stloc.1
```

---

The `value is true` version mentioned in the comments is almost the same as Expression 1:

```
IL_0008: ldloc.0
IL_0009: isinst [System.Runtime]System.Boolean
IL_000e: brfalse.s IL_0018

IL_0010: ldloc.0
IL_0011: unbox.any [System.Runtime]System.Boolean
IL_0016: br.s IL_0019
```

and has the added benefit of tolerating other types of values in `value`, not just `null`, `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the values range in terms of result both should be the same. For performance wrote a simple benchmark using [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet):

```cs
public class NullableBench
{
    private int Iterations = 10_000;

    [Params(true, false, null)]
    public object? Value { get; set; }

    [Benchmark]
    public bool Ternary()
    {
        bool result = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
        {
            result |= Value == null ? false : (bool)Value;
        }

        return result;
    }
    
    // suggested by IDE
    [Benchmark]
    public bool NullCheckAndCast()
    {
        bool result = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
        {
            result |=  Value != null && (bool)Value;
        }

        return result;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public bool Cast()
    {
        bool result = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
        {
            result |=  (bool?)Value == true;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Based on the results on my machine the cast option seems to be significantly slower:

| Method | Value | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ternary | ? | 4.413 us | 0.0118 us | 0.0105 us |
| NullCheckAndCast | ? | 4.463 us | 0.0675 us | 0.0631 us |
| Cast | ? | 70.407 us | 0.2566 us | 0.2401 us |
| Ternary | False | 6.702 us | 0.0291 us | 0.0273 us |
| NullCheckAndCast | False | 6.954 us | 0.0216 us | 0.0191 us |
| Cast | False | 88.480 us | 0.8313 us | 0.6942 us |
| Ternary | True | 6.700 us | 0.0359 us | 0.0336 us |
| NullCheckAndCast | True | 6.896 us | 0.0219 us | 0.0205 us |
| Cast | True | 88.598 us | 0.6308 us | 0.5268 us |

Updated with `Value is true` approach by [@GSerg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11683/gserg):

| Method | Value | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ternary | ? | 4.404 us | 0.0106 us | 0.0094 us |
| NullCheckAndCast | ? | 4.396 us | 0.0095 us | 0.0084 us |
| ValueIsTrue | ? | 7.022 us | 0.1385 us | 0.1361 us |
| Cast | ? | 71.324 us | 1.1534 us | 1.0789 us |
| Ternary | False | 6.676 us | 0.0202 us | 0.0189 us |
| NullCheckAndCast | False | 6.702 us | 0.0158 us | 0.0147 us |
| ValueIsTrue | False | 9.826 us | 0.1923 us | 0.3160 us |
| Cast | False | 87.950 us | 0.3554 us | 0.2968 us |
| Ternary | True | 6.706 us | 0.0269 us | 0.0251 us |
| NullCheckAndCast | True | 6.698 us | 0.0451 us | 0.0376 us |
| ValueIsTrue | True | 9.890 us | 0.1851 us | 0.1731 us |
| Cast | True | 87.881 us | 0.1873 us | 0.1660 us |